# How to declare a project dependency in SBT 0.10?

Tags: scala, sbt

I use SBT `0.10.0`.

How do I download/retrieve project dependencies?

For example, for [slf4s](https://github.com/weiglewilczek/slf4s) only this line is mentioned:

```
val slf4s = "com.weiglewilczek.slf4s" %% "slf4s" % "1.0.6
```

Where do I need to put this line, and how do I get the library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume you're using SBT 0.10.0, because earlier versions will put your deps in `lib_managed` automatically.

In `build.sbt`, put the following line:

```
retrieveManaged := true
```

Comment: I did add that line, but sbt does not seem to pick up my project/build/Project.scala file. Is there anything else to set?  I use SBT 0.10.0

Comment: It sounds like your project file is in the 0.7 location (`project/build`) instead of 0.10 (just `project`), See [this full example](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Full-Configuration-Example).

Answer (score 2):

You create a `project/build` subdirectory in your project and put a scala file with the above content there.

Then when you start sbt from your project root directory the

```
update
```

command will retrieve your dependencies.

Note that it will only analyse your project configuration once by default. If you change it, you have to call `reload`

UPDATE:

let the project class extend DefaultProject:

```
class SomeProjectName(info: ProjectInfo) extends DefaultProject(info)
```

Comment: I added a file Project.scala

import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

class Project extends Build {
  val slf4s = "com.weiglewilczek.slf4s" %% "slf4s" % "1.0.6"
}

Is something wrong here? It does not get the library after update and refresh

Comment: For some reason sbt did not pick up the project class. But it did retrieve the library if I added this line in build.sbt:    libraryDependencies += "com.weiglewilczek.slf4s" %% "slf4s" % "1.0.6"

Comment: This is because 0.10 finds `build.sbt`, and the suggestion above seems to be for 0.7. See [here](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Full-Configuration-Example) for a 0.10 project file example.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which version of sbt you are using.

For 0.10, Daniel C. Sobral made a blog post about creation of an sbt project:
[dcsobral-project-creation-guide](http://dcsobral.blogspot.com/2011/06/very-quick-guide-to-project-creation-on.html)

Maybe this helps.