# SBT doesn't seem to download transitive dependencies with a custom repository?

Tags: sbt

I'm new to SBT, using version 1.0 and a custom repository, and I've set the "retrieveManaged" flag mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703292/retrieving-project-dependencies-with-sbt), but it seems that SBT only downloads the directly requested JARs, but not any of the JARs upon which those JARs depend.  And yes, the repository is using the customary default format described in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342079/how-can-i-retrieve-snapshot-dependencies-from-nexus-using-sbt) (though SBT/Ivy doesn't seem capable of retrieving snapshots, either, but that's a separate problem, I expect).  The repository does not require any kind of authentication, FYI.

Here's a slightly generified version of my built.sbt file:

```
name := "MyProject"

organization := "com.myorg"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.9.0"

scalacOptions += "-deprecation"

retrieveManaged := true

resolvers += Resolver.url("myorg", url("http://host.com//content/groups/public"))

libraryDependencies += "com.myorg" % "otherproject" % "1.0"

fork in run := true
```

The requested "otherproject" JAR file loads fine, but SBT/Ivy seems to have no interest in opening up its POM and downloading the other JARs it needs to operate.  This seems like it should be a fairly basic function (Maven does it, for example) but I have no idea how to convince SBT/Ivy to do so.  (And the [documentation assures us](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Library-Management) that SBT is, in fact, supposed to do this: "By default, these declarations fetch all project dependencies, transitively".)

I believe I must be doing something wrong, but have no idea -- given how simple and vanilla this basic configuration is -- what it could be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard, Maven-style repositories are declared like:

```
resolvers += "myorg" at "http://host.com/content/groups/public"
```

More details are at the [Library Management](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management) page you linked to and on the [Resolvers](http://scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Resolvers) page.

Typically, one only uses `Resolver.url` when specifying non-standard layouts.

Comment: If this answer doesn't help, please post the output of `last update` after a `clean` and the output of `show dependency-classpath`, assuming there are no error messages.